# Struggling to pass data to UI - Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, object, parsing

Good day, I'm trying to pass data to my Profile UI View.

This is my Customer Class:

```
class Customer {
    // Creating a customer
    let name: String
    let surname: String
    let contactNo: String
    let email: String
   
    init(name: String,surname: String,contactNo: String,email: String) {
        
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.contactNo = contactNo
        self.email = email
    }
}
```

This is my code whereby I try to parse data from Firestore to display a customers details:

```
    class ProfileCus: UIViewController {
    
        // Labels to display data
        @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var surnameLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var emailLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var contactLabel: UILabel!
        
        // Reference to customer collection in Firestore
        private var  customerRefCollection: CollectionReference!
        
        // Customer Object
        private var customer: Customer?
        
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
    
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
            
            customerRefCollection = Firestore.firestore().collection("customers")
            
            nameLabel.text = customer?.name
            surnameLabel.text = customer?.surname
            emailLabel.text = customer?.email
            contactLabel.text = customer?.contactNo
            
        }
        
// This function notifies the view controller that the view is about to load so it is best to acquire the data in here before the view loads so that it will be ready to display.

        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            // Get the current user ID
            let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
            // Locate the user information on Firestore
            customerRefCollection.document(userID!).getDocument { (snapshot, error) in
                if let err = error {
                    debugPrint("Error fetching documents: \(err)")
                }
                else {
                    // Ensure that if there's nothing in the document that the function returns
                    guard let snap = snapshot else {return}
                    // Parse the data to the customer model
                    let data = snap.data()
                    
                    let name = data?["name"] as? String ?? ""
                    let surname = data?["surname"] as?  String ?? ""
                    let email = data?["email"] as? String ?? ""
                    let contact = data?["contact no"] as? String ?? ""
                    // Create the customer and pass it to the global variable
                    let cus = Customer(name: name, surname: surname, contactNo: contact, email: email)
                    self.customer = cus
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Everything on the Firestore side is working fine and I am able to read/retrieve data but I'm struggling to pass the data to my UI via my Customer Class. Using print statements it seems as if the customer object is nil.

[Output once the code runs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoUsA.png)

Comment: Is `self.customer = cus` called? If so, let me ask you this: `nameLabel.text = customer?.name` is called BEFORE or after `self.customer = cus`? You are missing the async concept and the fact that `viewWillAppear()` should be called after `viewDidLoad()`?

Comment: Code like `customer?.name` says you don't care whether `customer` is nil or not.  I suggest not using it unless that's what you really mean.  Test the value instead and at least print a message so you know what's happening.

Comment: Larme - I might be totally wrong but I assumed that viewWillAppear gets run before the view loads, so I thought it will be best to get the data in there and have it ready before the screen loads but obviously my assumption is incorrect. Do you suggest that I create a new function and put all of this in there?

Comment: Phillip Mills - I had an error saying that the class does not have initializers so I googled the use of code like customer?.name. I struggled to find out how to initiate the private var customers at the top. do you have a suggestion on how I can do this?

Comment: why not make `Customer` as `Struct` ?

Comment: Instead of `customer?.name`, you could make the assignments inside a block that says `if let customer = customer {` [bunch of code] `} else { print("No customer!") }`.  That way you would know what problem needed solving rather than wondering why your UI fields were empty.

Comment: @Phillip Mills, thanks I will literally appreciate any suggestions to learn how to parse data correctly. However, after trying the above it throws a compiler error saying: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Customer'

Comment: @jawadAli - Swift still insists on an initializer

Comment: Are you still using `customer?` in the assignment?  (The point of `if let` is to get rid of that.)

Comment: @PhillipMills No I changed it like you said. I initialized the customer object with random strings and it updated the UI view YESSS! Could you help me understand what the issue is? I suspect that the data is not being parsed to the object, should I get out of the viewWillAppear() function and create a different function to call in viewDidLoad() ? My only issue with that will be the loading time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func getDataFromFirebase(completion:@escaping() -> ()){



let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
            // Locate the user information on Firestore
            customerRefCollection.document(userID!).getDocument { (snapshot, error) in
                if let err = error {
                    debugPrint("Error fetching documents: \(err)")
                }
                else {
                    // Ensure that if there's nothing in the document that the function returns
                guard let snap = snapshot else {return}
                // Parse the data to the customer model
                let data = snap.data()
                
                let name = data?["name"] as? String ?? ""
                let surname = data?["surname"] as?  String ?? ""
                let email = data?["email"] as? String ?? ""
                let contact = data?["contact no"] as? String ?? ""
                // Create the customer and pass it to the global variable
                let cus = Customer(name: name, surname: surname, contactNo: contact, email: email)
                self.customer = cus
            }
completion()
        }
    }


getDataFromFirebase{
customerRefCollection = Firestore.firestore().collection("customers")
        
        nameLabel.text = customer?.name
        surnameLabel.text = customer?.surname
        emailLabel.text = customer?.email
        contactLabel.text = customer?.contactNo
```

}

So what you're basically doing here is you're first getting the data from the firebase and only after this work is done, hence the completion block you will be setting your data to the view. You can call the method simply in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Firstly, thank you so so much! I am truly grateful. Can I ask that you please verify the syntax for me because after adding it to my project it through a few errors and this is the first time I am dealing with a completion() so I am not sure where everything should go. The block inside the 2nd getDataFromFirebase{block} down at the bottom, is it supposed to be there?

Comment: Please assist with this?

Comment: Define the GetDataFromFirebase anywhere in the view controller. And call the function on viewDidLoad and the block you meant is where the handling takes place. The block inside the 2nd getDataFromFirebase executes only after it gets the data. Getting data from server is often an asynchronous task(it generally happens in the background). So with the completion what you are simply notified, ok sir It got your data, and inside the completion you basically tell it, you don't need to tell me, but do what I said. So it looks if there is any completion handler and does the task likewise.